# Redirects using routes.yaml in the root folder .magento/routes.yaml

Tags: magento2.3, redirect, routes

Can anybody for the love of god help me with the syntax here. I feel like i've tried everything and everytime i try to push this to the magento cloud it complains about something or another.

Here's my latest iteration:

```
# The routes of the project.
#
# Each route describes how an incoming URL is going to be processed.



"http://{default}/":
    type: upstream
    upstream: "mymagento:php"
    paths: "^/catalogsearch/result((/)|(/\\?)|(/\\?[a-z])|(/\\?[a-z]=))?$"
    to: "https://www.example.com", regexp: true
```

Error message when deploying to cloud is this:

```
E: Error parsing configuration files:
    - routes: Error loading file: while parsing a block mapping
          in ".magento/routes.yaml", line 8, column 5
        did not find expected key
          in ".magento/routes.yaml", line 11, column 39
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting a redirection of `/catalogsearch/..` to `www.example.com`? If so, you might need to place your redirect paths hierarchically under `redirects`:

```
http://{default}/:
  type: upstream
  upstream: mymagento:php
  redirects:
    paths:
      ^/catalogsearch/result((/)|(/\\?)|(/\\?[a-z])|(/\\?[a-z]=))?$:
        to: https://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result$1
        regexp: true
        code: 302
```

See more in [Partial-route redirects](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-routes-more-redir.html#cloud-route-partial)

Comment: I'm looking to redirect these two links... https://example.com/catalogsearch/result/ and /catalogsearch/result/?=

Comment: they should both go back to the homepage because they are 503... anything after the = equals sign that has a valid query should function properly.